# Strange results while using numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I am getting two different results for some inputs but not others. Let me explain using the concrete example. I have the following function:

```
In [86]: def f(x, p):
    ...:     n = len(p)
    ...:     tot = 0
    ...:     for i in range(n):
    ...:         tot += p[i] * x**(n-i-1)
    ...:     return tot
```

`p` is an array with very small values:

```
In [87]: p
Out[87]: 
array([ -3.93107522e-45,   9.17048746e-40,  -8.11593366e-35,
         3.05584286e-30,  -1.06065846e-26,  -3.03946945e-21,
         1.05944707e-16,  -1.56986924e-12,   1.07293061e-08,
        -3.22670121e-05,   1.12072912e-01])
```

Now consider the outputs:

```
In [90]: [f(i, p) for i in range(11, 20)]
Out[90]: 
[0.11171927108787173,
 0.1116872502272328,
 0.1116552507123586,
 0.11162327253386167,
 0.11159131568235707,
 0.11155938014846242,
 0.1115274659227979,
 0.11149557299598616,
 0.11146370135865244]

In [88]: [f(i, p) for i in np.array(range(11, 20))]
Out[88]: 
[0.11171927108787173,
 0.1116872502272328,
 0.1116552507123586,
 0.11162327253386167,
 0.11159131568235707,
 0.11155938014846242,
 0.1115274659227979,
 0.11149557299598616,
 0.11146370135865244]
```

As you can see, these outputs are exactly same as they should be. The only difference is that in one case I am using `range(a, b)` while in the other case I am converting that range to a numpy array.

But now, let us change the values inside the range:

```
In [91]: [f(i, p) for i in range(50001, 50010)]
Out[91]: 
[-0.011943965521167818,
 -0.011967640114171604,
 -0.011991315947644229,
 -0.012014993019120554,
 -0.012038671327427961,
 -0.012062350870605351,
 -0.012086031644648818,
 -0.012109713648648865,
 -0.012133396879791744]

In [92]: [f(i, p) for i in np.array(range(50001, 50010))]
Out[92]: 
[491.26519430165808,
 491.32457916465478,
 491.38395932037008,
 491.38726606180143,
 491.44663641006275,
 491.50600185375316,
 491.56536239249812,
 491.56864971072332,
 491.6280006336612]
```

And they are not even close! Am I missing something ridiculously simple?

Comment: That looks like an interger range issue. on newer python versions ints have unlimited range, you can check that by typing something ridiculous like 10**100-1. numpy ints are C longs so they do not provide that luxury.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the fact that ordinary Python integers are arbitrary-precision, while NumPy integers are fixed-size.

This:

```
x**(n-i-1)
```

overflows with the NumPy inputs.

Comment: I see. What is the remedy then because I have numpy array in the actual code. In fact, it is a Pandas Series.

Answer (score 1):

The values in `f(x, p)` for `x` in the error case, are type `numpy.int32`.  They can overflow.  The fix in this case is relatively straight forward, convert the values to `int`:

```
tot += p[i] * np.asarray(x).astype(int) ** (n - i - 1)
```

Comment: That may not work when `x` is passed as a numpy array. Right?

Comment: Hmm. However, it throws an error in my case: `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`